# Trying to list all the files within a certain directory using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to select a folder using the FileDialog option. Once this is selected, the folder path directory is shown in cell F12. After that is done I am trying to list all the files within the folder in certain columns based on their criteria (File Name, File size, etc.) I can get the file path to be written in cell F12, but I am stuck past that. Here's what I have so far:

```
    Const Column_A As Integer = 1
    Const Column_B As Integer = 2
    Const Column_C As Integer = 3
    Const Column_D As Integer = 4
    Const Column_E As Integer = 5
    Const Column_F As Integer = 6
    Const Column_U As Integer = 21

' Create an OpenFileDialog object

' Initialize the OpenFileDialog to look for DWG files.
openFile1.Title = "Open File Dialog"    'Title header for dialog box
openFile1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Desktop...." 'Inital directory for file dialog box
openFile1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|" 'Filter all files
openFile1.Multiselect = True 'Allows the user to select to select multiple files

If openFile1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then 'This gives the "ok" to actually open the pop-up window
    Header_Info_Sheet.Range("E11").Value = "File Path:"
    strFileName = openFile1.FileName  'Stores the Filename inside the variable
    Header_Info_Sheet.Range("F11").Value = strFileName 'Shows the variable FilePath
End If

Dim strFileSize As String = ""
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("")
Dim aryFi As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
Dim fi As IO.FileInfo

Const Row = 18

For Each fi In aryFi
    strFileSize = (Math.Round(fi.Length / 1024)).ToString()
    Cells(Row, Column_A) = ("File Name: {0}", fi.Name)
    Cells(Row, Column_B) = ("File Full Name: {0}", fi.FullName)
    Cells(Row, Column_C) = ("File Size (KB): {0}", strFileSize)
    Cells(Row, Column_D) = ("File Extension: {0}", fi.Extension)
    Cells(Row, Column_E) = ("Last Accessed: {0}", fi.LastAccessTime)
    Cells(Row, Column_F) = ("Read Only: {0}", (fi.Attributes.ReadOnly = True).ToString)
Next
```

Comment: You want to just increase the row? Where are you stuck? :) Why did you define it as const then?

Comment: Why does it seem that you're using an `OpenFileDialog` to select a folder?

Answer (score 0):

Most of that code should only execute if the "OK" was returned.  Move it all inside your If statement.

Then, simply change:

```
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("")
```

To:

```
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(strFileName)
```

so that `di` actually points to the folder that was selected.

You also need to increment `Row` somehow so that each file is in a different row?